# LastPass extension not showing the icon?

Tags: lastpass, password-manager

I'm using the lastpass extension in my browser and lastpass doesn't show the icon for the text input field for the OTP purpose.

```
Text : <input  type="text" >
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G30ia.png)

But in some cases, it shows an icon for an input field type of 'text' and an autocomplete attribute value of 'email'.

```
Text : <input  type="text" autocomplete="email" >
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2rlb.png)

May I know the reason why it shows the icon with the autocomplete attribute value as "Email"?